# C++ new operator

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

Let's say I have a

```
class A
{
  int A1;
  void Af();
};
```

Then I do:

```
A  hA;
A* pA = new A();
```

now, `hA` is an object in the stack; I can use

```
hA.A1 = 52 // for example
```

but `pA` just points to `class A`, how is that useful or handy? (any examples please?)

second issue:

when I did `A* pA = new A()`; did I allocate anything in the heap? was there any `malloc()` in the background? if not, then why not? and how come int *p_array = new int[5] will allocate memory in the heap of 5 ints and not A* pA = new A()?

Comment: `A hA = new A();` is not valid syntax; what is your actual question?

Comment: What you wrote isn't valid C++. Don't think about heap and stack, and instead remember that `new` creates a *dynamic* object whose lifetime you must manage manually.

Comment: `int[] *A` isn't valid C++ syntax either.  Are you sure you're using C++?

Comment: These variable names are just for this example, right?

Comment: No tutorial is helping you? Are you sure what you read was a c++ tutorial?

Comment: @Kam: Sorry, I think I replaced your edit (didn't realize it was coming from the asker of the question) with more minor formatting changes.

Comment: OP needs to read [his C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources); these are _basics_.

Comment: Ok guys, really sorry I updated the post again

Comment: @Kam: Updating the post does not constitute reading a C++ book from cover to cover, twice.

Comment: Get a better book on C++ that illustrates and provides examples of usage of pointers, references and dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A  hA = new A();
```

leads to a compiler error. The correct way of defining a variable "on the stack" is

```
A ha;
```

> but pA just points to class A, how is that useful or handful (any examples please?)

In some place in the memory, you have an object of type A, and pa points to it. If you want to set the A1 member of that object to 52, you write

```
pA->A1 = 52;
```

The why is it useful part is not a real question.

> when I did A* pA = new A(); did I allocate anything in the heap?

Yes, you did. `new` does two things: it allocates memory and invokes the constructor.

> was there any malloc() in the background?

That is unspecified, but in many implementations `new` is implemented via `malloc`

> and how come int[] *A = A[42] will allocate memory in the heap of 42 ints and not A* pA = new A() ?

This, sir, is also a compiler error. What you meant was

```
int* A = new A[42];
```

This is the `operator new[]` which allocates arrays on the heap and calls constructors if necessary (in case of ints it isn't).

Comment: `\`A hA = new A();\` is a compiler error` No, it's invalid code that'll lead to one being generated \*ducks\*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: How is it not a compiler error? there is no implicit conversion from A* to A

Comment: Code and compiler errors are two different things. The former is a sequence of characters, whilst the latter is something that your compiler emits when the sequence of characters didn't represent a valid C++ program

Comment: Well, I _did_ say "\*ducks\*"; I was hoping that you'd have detected my irony.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your reply, honeslty ive been reading alot its just some stuff Im not really getting pleasee bare with me. when you do int*B= new B[42] you are allocating and reserving 42*sizeof int in the heap and returning a pointer to it "B". When you do A *pA= new A() what do you put in the heap? do we actually reserve in the heap memory the size of A1 and Af() (the contents of classA)? or do we just store and reseve the memory of the address that points to classA?

Comment: @Kam: When you write `T* p = new T;`, you have a variable p on the stack (size of a pointer) which holds a pointer to an object that is allocated on the heap (of type T). When you write T* p = T[10], again, a pointer p is allocated on the stack, 10 consecutive T's on the heap, and p points to the first of these T's.

Comment: Ok but if you now do this, T oT; and then you do p=&oT; p will then point to the location of T so what happens with the heap memory that p used to point to?

Comment: sorry typo: Ok but if you now do this, T oT; and then you do p=&oT; p will then point to the location of oT so what happens with the heap memory that p used to point to?

Comment: @Kam: What happens is called a memory leak. The object is still in memory, but you have no handles to it. So you can't delete it(call the destructor and free the memory)

Answer (score 0):

Once use for pointers to objects is when the capacity or the data quantity is unknown at compile-time.  A good example is receiving text from a User.
Will the user enter 5 characters, 10, 1k?

If my program allocates 1k and the user never enters more than 32 characters, this is a waste of space.

Another use for dynamic memory allocation is passing information between objects:
Object 1 creates a book, but is not responsible for destroying it.
Object 2 proofreads the book, generates a list of corrections, but doesn't destroy the book.
Object 3 Adds tables to the book, still doesn't destroy it.
Object 4 Saves the book, then destroys it.

Please read the "C++ FAQ" for fast answers to common C++ Questions.

Answer (score 0):

> but `pA` just points to `class A`, how is that useful or handy? (any examples please?)

That's not the case. pA points to an A object, so `*pA` is an object just like `hA` is an object:

```
(*pA).A1 = 52 // for example
```

When you do `A* pA = new A()`, yes a dynamic allocation occurs. Not necessarily a call to `malloc()`, but something. (Ignoring uses of user defined `operator new` which can do anything you like)

`new A()` does two main things. It allocates space for the object somewhere. And if that succeeds then it constructs an object of the type you requested at that location. If the object is constructed successfully then it simply returns a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 0):

> but pA just points to class A, how is that useful or handy? (any examples please?)

It's useful and handy because now you have the address of an instance of class A that does not exsist on the stack, but on the heap.  So it will survive if you fall out of scope(return from a function ect).  You can pass the pointer around all over the place and you instance remains

> when I did A* pA = new A(); did I allocate anything in the heap? was there any malloc() in the background?

Yes Yes and yes, this is the point of the new operator.